# Sending parameters with history.back()?

Tags: javascript, navigation, salesforce, salesforce-lightning, lwc

Is it possible to send a track/api variable to the next cmp, while using history.back() in LWC.

```
        this.var1 = false;
        var compDefinition = {
            componentDef: "c:Component-to-navigate",
            attributes: {
                leadId: this.SomeLeadId,
                SomeId: this.SomeId,                   
                Variable-To-send: true
            }
        };
        var encodedCompDef = btoa(JSON.stringify(compDefinition));
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: 'standard__webPage',
            attributes: {
                url: '/one/one.app#' + encodedCompDef
            }
        });
```

Instead of this i want to use history.back(), and also need to pass ' Variable-To-send' with this is this even possible ? tried directly with onclick funtion, not working.
Apart from navigation any other way ? basically i dont want to reload the previous page. ? tried history.back(), windows.location = etc, but not able to pass the same..

Please help with the approach if possible thanks.

Comment: My understanding of history.back is that browser reads page from cache, no new Paramus, no network trips. "Undo" called on already local content as if navigation forward never happened...

Answer (score 1):

well, history.back() method loads the previous URL (page) in the history list and only works if a previous page exists.

So, we cannot set any parameter while calling the history.back().

However, we can simulate the same thing by using some temporary storage that can store the parameter value that we want to communicate to the other component between the pages.

to do so we can either make use of:

- local storage
- session storage
- cookie
- or any other storage place where we can keep the data and access :)

Example:
we can use local storage like below:

```
// to set the param value
localStorage.setItem('param1', 'value1');
localStorage.setItem('param2', 'value2');

// going back or any navigation
history.back();

// to get the value at any other place
const param1 = localStorage.getItem('param1');
const param2 = localStorage.getItem('param2');


// to remove the data from storage
localStorage.removeItem('param1');
localStorage.removeItem('param2');

// or 

localStorage.clear();
```